# Custom colors and dark mode not working in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind CSS for a personal project and I'd love to use custom colors,
I'm using the trick `hover:text-[#007560]` but it would be nicer and easier if i had my entire palette in the `tailwind.config.js`.

[image: html desired]

In the photo there's the desired code that I want to achieve.

I tried everything said in other posts but none of them works for me.

Also dark mode has the same exact problem: it doesn't works.

Seems like this file is not read.

My code looks like this, but as soon as I try to use `bg-cherry` nothing happens: "stock" colors remains but I can't see my customs.

How can I resolve?

I also tried to re-run both the project and this command
`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/style/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

(the path is where I store all css files to have a clean project)

[image: actual tailwind confige]

Answer (score 4):

The property 'darkMode' in tailwind doesn't take a boolean, but a string.
You can refer to the doc : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode
A good link : https://flowbite.com/docs/customize/dark-mode/

Comment: Even with your solution this file does not work. Seems like it isn't recognised.

Comment: And tailwind is working in your other file ?

Comment: Maybe it's cause you have 2 times the `theme` properties : 

`theme: {
   theme: {`

should look like that :
`theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
your colors
}`
If you want you can install `TailwindIntelissense` on Vscode and go in the output of the extension it will notify you if there are mistakes in your config. + the last line of your content object is useless, tailwind goes from the root to scan your files, the second one is sufficient.

Comment: omg that works, cannot believe how dumb am I... thanks!